# Why this Makefile fails to build the project?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
OBJS    = main_exp_par_auto.o
SOURCE  = ../main/main_exp_par_auto.cpp
HEADER  =   ../Division_Euclidean_space.h   ../Find_diameter.h  ../Find_k_max.h ../Householder.h    ../IO.h ../Mean_variance.h  ../Point.h  ../Random_generator.h   ../Random_kd_forest.h   ../Tree.h   ../Auto_random_kd_forest.h
OUT     =   geraf
CXX = g++
FLAGS   =   -pthread    -std=c++0x  -DRKD_PAR   -O3 -Wall

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX)  $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)   $(FLAGS)
    make    -f  makefiles/Makefile_exp_par_auto clean

# create/compile the individual files >>separately<< 
main_exp_par_auto.o:    main/main_exp_par_auto.cpp
    $(CXX)  -c  main/main_exp_par_auto.cpp  $(FLAGS)

.PHONY : all
# clean house
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)

# do a bit of accounting
count:
    wc $(SOURCE) $(HEADER)
```

and the folder looks like this:

[image]

However, I am getting:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:/media/gsamaras/a6cd1464-abf1-4a7b-b4a2-61f584d4cb32/gsamaras/code/C++/kd_GeRaF-master/makefiles$ make -f Makefile_exp_par_auto 
make: *** No rule to make target `main/main_exp_par_auto.cpp', needed by `main_exp_par_auto.o'.  Stop.
```

This is an old project of mine and that was supposed to be working, how to fix this?

Comment: In what directory are you running the `make` command? BTW, I believe that putting object files in a separate directory is a bad habit, notably for small projects...

Comment: Oh yeah @BasileStarynkevitch that should do the trick! Hmm so what you suggest about them?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not putting object files into separate directories risks mixing debug/release object files and then wasting time debugging it. Putting object files into separate directories is the best practice.

Comment: No, just `make clean` before `make debug` or `make release`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You might be surprised, but people forget `make clean` part. In fact, with robust build systems you never use this command at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking it from `makefiles` directory, whereas `main` directory is on the same level. It looks for `main/main_exp_par_auto.cpp` and fails to find it.

Invoke `make` like that:

```
make -C /media/gsamaras/a6cd1464-abf1-4a7b-b4a2-61f584d4cb32/gsamaras/code/C++/kd_GeRaF-master -f makefiles/Makefile_exp_par_auto
```